# Two regex patterns, changing the pattern of an html text input depending on initial value from database

Tags: php, html, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to create a PHP conditional statement for a form input that will return a regex pattern depending on the initial value returned from the database.  Here is my (not working correctly) current code:

```
<input type="text" 
    name="comp" 
    minlength="4" 
    maxlength="4" 
    pattern="<?php ($comp === '0.00' ? "/\d\.\d\d/" : "/^(?!0.00)\d\.\d\d/")  ?>" 
    value="<?php echo $comp; ?>">
```

I'm trying to write a statement that says if `$comp` is loaded from the database with a value of 0.00 the input form needs to have the pattern of digits in the form of x.xx but it has to have that format with 2 decimal places.  If `$comp` is loaded with a value of anything other than 0.00, like 0.25 the pattern must not allow 0.00 but can allow any other combo of digits in the form of x.xx.

Comment: $comp === '0.00' is a comparison. It doesn't set the value of $comp. So, when you echo $comp, it has whatever it had when you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what you want, but it is possible you want:

```
<input type="text" 
name="comp" 
minlength="4" 
maxlength="4" 
pattern="<?php echo ($comp === '0.00' ? "/\d\.\d\d/" : "/^(?!0.00)\d\.\d\d/")  ?>" 
value="<?php echo $comp; ?>">
```

The echo prints. You weren't printing anything.